# QT QBytearray count character

Tags: qt, qstring, qbytearray

How I can count characters in `QByteArray`, for example I have `QByteArray` and I want to know how many "*" in this array.

Comment: Can you guarantee each character will always be one byte in size?

Answer (score 2):

From `QByteArray` [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html):

```
int QByteArray::count ( const char * str ) const

This is an overloaded function.

Returns the number of (potentially overlapping) occurrences of string str in the byte array.
```

[count](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#count-2).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QByteArray::indexOf(char ch, int from = 0) const` inside a loop.

Maybe this:

```
int i = 0, counter = 0;

while((i = array.indexOf("*", i)) >= 0)
 counter++;
```

Comment: That would work, but it's preferable to use the built-in `count()` method, as mentioned above.